# How to plot a certain surface? What is its parametric equation?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

The surface show below is very beautiful; however, I don't know its function either as an implicit function or in parametric form.

Anyone have an idea about it and how to draw it with *Mathematica*?

[image: Beautiful surface]

Comment: One way might be to browse on-line the Mathematica GUIDE book for graphics by Trott at google books http://books.google.com/books?id=9DGhukeFNLIC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false  If anyone done something like the above, it will be in that book. Many more amazing plots there.

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with this? http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysanco.com%2Fwenda%2Findex.php%3Fclass%3Ddiscuss%26action%3Dquestion_item%26questionid%3D6138

Comment: Can you please give an answer to @belisarius. You have had 4 days to respond and you are back here again today.

Comment: @belisarius I have no access to this due to the network being blocked

Comment: Strange ... at least @MikeHoneychurch, four others and me aren't suffering any blocking. Someone is playing dirty with your network access.

Comment: Google services are usually instable here;

Comment: @belisarius I did post similar questions in other forum and only got answers here.

Comment: @belisarius I think the Chinese webpage you referred to is a Q/A forum in China which is popular among some academic people. Basically it's the same question as this one, only was asked earlier (15 Nov). And the OP there answered his/her own question 3 days ago. I suspect it's the same person as our OP here. So, IMO, this is not an abuse :)

Comment: @Silvia Thanks! And yes, he just answered that at my original comment. Personally I dislike cross-posting without leaving a notice because the OP is the only one who can get benefits from the answers on both sites. But in this case, it's worse, as the answer in the Chinese site is a copy of the code here, without attribution. A shame.

Comment: About the blocking, It really depends. Geography, timing, ISP, etc. They all play a part on the power of the GFW. Say, we were having [*Lianghui*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lianghui) here a few days ago, thus many oversea sites are temporarily blocked..

Comment: @belisarius thanks for pointing out this. I would add a link to here the original answer. As a matter of fact, I also post the similar answer in other places before with original link attached.

Comment: @belisarius Have taken a close look at his post there, and yes I totally agree with you. It's not right copying the whole answer without leaving any ref to the original one... Hope OP can add this information.

Comment: @LCFactorization Hi. Don't be frightened! Most people here are super nice! Just keep in mind some common manners and form the habit of honour others’ authorship. :)

Comment: @Silvia, LCFactorization. Ok, everything is in its place now. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @belisarius You are welcome!

Comment: @LCFactorization We could chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11720/conversation-between-lcfactorization-and-silvia).

Comment: your question lead to this one on a sibling site: [Rotation transformation of a parametrized plot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192513) :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Consider this:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 RotationTransform[a, {0, 1, 0}][{0, 0, Sin[3 a] + 5/4}],
  {a, 0, 2 Pi}, Evaluated -> True]
```

> [image]

Now rotate this around a circle, while rotating it at the same time around its' origin:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 RotationTransform[b, {0, 0, 1}][{6, 0, 0} + 
   RotationTransform[a + 3 b, {0, 1, 0}][{0, 0, Sin[3 a] + 5/4}]],
    {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 40, Evaluated -> True]
```

> [image]

**EDIT:**

A color function, omitting surface mesh, fixing direction of rotation and adding a hint of transparency, like the original:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 RotationTransform[b, {0, 0, 1}][{6, 0, 0} + 
   RotationTransform[a - 3 b + Pi, {0, 1, 0}][{0, 0, Sin[3 a] + 5/4}]],
 {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 40, 
 ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[#, 0, 1 - #, 4/5] &[1/2 + {1, -1}.{#1, #2}/2] &),
 Mesh -> False, Evaluated -> True]
```

> [image]

This might be slightly more intuitive way to write `ColorFunction` using `Blend` and `Opacity` in `PlotStyle`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 RotationTransform[b, {0, 0, 1}][{6, 0, 0} + 
   RotationTransform[a - 3 b + Pi, {0, 1, 0}][{0, 0, Sin[3 a] + 5/4}]],
 {a, 0, 2 Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotPoints -> 40, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[4/5], 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, Blue}, 1/2 + {1, -1}.{#1, #2}/2] &), 
 Mesh -> False, Evaluated -> True]
```

Comment: +1 very neat! `ColorFunction` would be a nice addition...:)

Comment: @cormullion Added. :)

Comment: (+1 i) Thank you! :)

Comment: @kirma Cool! How do you change the Opacity?

Comment: @LCFactorization Opacity is the optional fourth argument of `RGBColor`, `4/5` in this case.

Comment: @kirma thank you!

Comment: Very nice use of `RotationTransform`

Comment: @cormullion, I love the imaginary upvote. +Sqrt[2I]  :-)

Comment: @SimonWoods Now we just need to figure out how to `Abs[]` them for a rep boost :D

Comment: @kirma See this!: http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysanco.com%2Fwenda%2Findex.php%3Fclass%3Ddiscuss%26action%3Dquestion_item%26questionid%3D6138

Comment: @belisarius I actually looked for the image included in the original question, and ran into that page back then. Only with a question, though. :)

Comment: Congratulations on an elusive Guru badge. :-)  (Elusive to everyone but Leonid, that is.)

Answer (score 21):

I'm adding this answer to put on record an answer to the second part the question, "what is the parametric equation?".

The parametric equation is implicit in Kirma's `RotationTransform` expression. To extract it, one need simply write something like

```
Clear[a, b]
quoit[a_, b_] := 
  Evaluate @ RotationTransform[b, {0, 0, 1}][{6, 0, 0} + 
    RotationTransform[a - 3 b + Pi, {0, 1, 0}][{0, 0, Sin[3 a] + 5/4}]]
```

The function defined by the above expression, looks like this

```
Definition @ quoit
```

> ```
> quoit[a_, b_] := 
>    {
>      Cos[b] (6 - (5/4 + Sin[3 a]) Sin[a - 3 b]), 
>      (6 - (5/4 + Sin[3 a]) Sin[a - 3 b]) Sin[b], 
>      -Cos[a - 3 b] (5/4 + Sin[3 a])
>    }
> ```

Comment: thank you very much ! very useful

Comment: Indeed; maybe I left this part a bit too much implied.

Comment: Also the order of wrapping rotation matrix is critical. When the foil rotates around the circle (outmost transform function), the Z axis is fixed. While it spins about its center, the attached Z axis changes direction. Thats why the transform with `{0,1,0}` is inside the first transform.