# How to enumerate all possible binary associations?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, combinatorics

Suppose I have a list of symbols like:

```
{a,b,c,d}
```

I would like to enumerate all possible binary associations (combining symbols and/or sublists pairwise):

```
{{{a,b},c},d}
{{a,b},{c,d}}
{a,{b,{c,d}}}
{{a,{b,c}},d}
{a,{{b,c},d}}
```

There should be altogether 5 solutions for this example. My question is how can I enumerate all such associations for a generic list?

I have tried

```
ReplaceList[{a,b,c,d},{u___,v_,w_,x___}:>{u,{v,w},x}]
```

But this only works for the first layer.

Comment: Kindly explain what you mean by a binary association. (I'm trying to reconcile your question with what I've found online at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) Does Silvia's output satisfy your idea of binary association?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I propose a more compact approach

```
f[list__] := Join @@ ReplaceList[{list}, {x__, y__} :> Tuples@{f[x], f[y]}]
f[x_] := {x};

f[a, b, c, d] // Column
```

> ```
> {a,{b,{c,d}}}
> {a,{{b,c},d}}
> {{a,b},{c,d}}
> {{a,{b,c}},d}
> {{{a,b},c},d}
> ```

One can note that the length of this list is the [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)

$$
C_n = \frac{1}{1+n}{2n\choose n}
$$

```
Length[f @@ ConstantArray[a, 6]]
CatalanNumber[6 - 1]
WolframAlpha["answer to life the universe and everything"]
```

> ```
> 42
> 42
> 42
> ```

Comment: +1 Much-much-much faster than mine!

Comment: I am wondering if someone can device a non-rule based solution...

Comment: +1 Very nice! I was looking along similar lines but trying to use `Thread` on the RHS of the rule. `Tuples` is inspired.

Comment: @ybeltukov Great solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: `WolframAlpha["Don't panic"]`

Answer (score 9):

I think one way is to do your `ReplaceList` repeatedly, until the result doesn't change any more.

```
FixedPoint[
 DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[
    Function[lst,
      If[# === {}, {lst}, #] &[
       ReplaceList[lst,
        {u___, v_, w_, x___} /;
          Nand[{u} === {}, {x} === {}] :>
         {u, {v, w}, x}]
       ]
      ] /@ #,
    1]] &,
 {Range[5]}
 ];

TreeForm /@ %
```

[image: binary association tree plots]

Comment: Hey Silvia! Long time no see :)

Comment: @YvesKlett Hi! Had a tough year without computers and just got my MMA home edition not long ago :)

Comment: Welcome baaaack - hope you are doing fine!

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks a lot :) You make me feel back to home~ Everything is great now. And I even got myself a Raspberry Pi :D

Comment: @Silvia Welcome back! Raspberry: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dmhF1rqaZk

Comment: @belisarius LOL Every time I watch this video, I can't stop laughing :D Thanks belisarius!

Comment: @Silvia Could you take a look at my comment under the question here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37698/193 and see if you can understand what is going on, please? (my google-Chinese isn't good enough to understand if someone is abusing our drive to help)

Answer (score 8):

How about a recursive approach?

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, func];
set = {a, b, c, d};

counter = 0;
rules = {};
func[{x_}] := x;
func[list_] := Module[{r}, DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[func /@ 
    ReplaceList[list, {a___, x_, y_, b___} :> {a, {x, y} /. 
    rules /. {x, y} :> (r = RandomReal[]; PrependTo[rules, {x, y} -> r]; r), b}],
   1]];

temp = func@set;
Fold[ReplaceAll, temp, Reverse /@ rules]
```

> ```
>   {
>    {{{a, b}, c}, d},
>    {{a, b}, {c, d}},
>    {{a, {b, c}}, d},
>    {a, {{b, c}, d}},
>    {a, {b, {c, d}}}
>    }
> ```

**Update**
Made it faster. Random reals are generated to denote parental nodes. There is an infinitesimal chance that a `set` of random reals might interfere with generated node-identifiers.

Comment: @Silvia Had to extend it to remove some redundancy. Please check. It is pretty slow for sets longer than 8 elements... Yours is definitely faster.

Comment: Sorry I used `set = Range[5]` for test, which caused the never stopping `//.`. You got my +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

In Mathematica 11, we don't have to write a solution ourselves.

M11 has [Groupings](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Groupings.html)

> Groupings[{a1,...,an},k]
>
> gives all possible groupings of a1,...,an taken k at a time.

So

`Groupings[{a, b, c, d}, 2]` gives

```
{{{{a, b}, c}, d}, {a, {{b, c}, d}}, {{a, {b, c}}, 
  d}, {a, {b, {c, d}}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}}
```

easy life with M11 :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't possibly compete with the beautiful solution provided by ybeltukov, but I had already started thinking about it, so here's what I came up with.

The first thing was to define a function to check whether a proposed partitioning has the correct properties:

```
twoQ[ll_List] := Length@ll == 2 && twoQ[ll[[1]]] && twoQ[ll[[2]]]
twoQ[ll_] := True;
```

Then, to find the partitioning:

```
t[{x_}] := {x}
t[ll_] := Flatten[Table[{l1, l2}, {j, 1, Length[ll] - 1},
     {l1, t@ll[[1 ;; j]]}, {l2, t@ll[[j + 1 ;; -1]]}], 2];
```

so that

```
t[{a,b,c,d}]
(* 
    {{a, {b, {c, d}}},
     {a, {{b, c}, d}},
     {{a, b}, {c, d}}, 
     {{a, {b, c}}, d}, 
     {{{a, b}, c}, d}} *)

 twoQ /@ %
 (* {True, True, True, True, True} *)
```