# Is there concise code for the list operation I want to perform?

Tags: list-manipulation, physics, partitions, group-theory, subset

Is there any concise syntax for the following partitioning of a list. Given
`{1, 2, 3, 4}`, I want to get the output as shown below. I have tried various function such as `Partition` and others, but I couldn't get the result I want.

> ```
> {1} {2, 3, 4, 5}
> {1, 2} {3, 4, 5}
> {1, 2, 3} {4, 5}
> {1, 2, 3, 4} {5}
> ```

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in function that does this, as this question as appeared before (but don't have time to find link right now). You can define a function that does the job like so: `splits[list_] := Table[{Take[list, n], Drop[list, n]}, {n, Length[list] - 1}]`

Comment: Related: [(5305)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5305/121), [(8528)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8528/121), [(32404)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32404/121), [(37869)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37869/121)

Answer (score 19):

```
Li = Range[5];
TakeDrop[Li, #] & /@ Range[Length[Li]-1] // Column[Row/@#]&
```

or, slightly shorter,

```
i = 1; TakeDrop[Li, i++] & /@ Most[Li] // Column[Row/@#]&
```

or, using just `Range` and organizing the result with `Transpose`:

```
Transpose[{Range[Range[4]], Range[1 + Range[4], 5]}] // Column[Row/@#]&
```

> [image]

For an arbitrary list of size `5`, say, `lst = {w, v, x, y, z}`,

```
lst[[#]] & /@ # & /@ Transpose[{Range[Range[4]], Range[1 + Range[4], 5]}] // format
```

> [image]

A few more alternatives:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, ☺]
f1 = Module[{i = 1, lst = #},  TakeDrop[lst, i++] & /@ Rest[lst]] &;
f2 = Module[{lst = #},  TakeDrop[lst, #] & /@ Range[Length[lst] - 1]] &;
f3 = Table[Partition[#, Length@#, 1, {-1, 1}, {}][[{i, i + Length@#}]], {i, Length@# - 1}]&
f4 = Module[{lst = #, l = Length@# - 1}, lst[[#]] & /@ # & /@ 
      Transpose[{Range[Range[l]], Range[1 + Range[l], l + 1]}]] &;
f5 = Module[{lst = #, r = Range[Length[#] - 1], l = Length@#, parts}, 
      parts =Transpose[{Range[r], Range[1 + r, l]}]; Extract[lst, List/@ #] &/@ parts]&;
f6 = Function[{x}, Most@MapIndexed[{x[[;; #2[[1]]]], x[[1 + #2[[1]] ;;]]} &, x]];
f7 = Table[Values@GroupBy[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, #], First[#] <= i &, Last /@ # &], 
      {i, Length[#] - 1}] &;
f8 = Rest@NestList[{Join[#[[1]], {#[[-1, 1]]}], #[[-1, 2 ;;]]} &, {{}, #}, Length@# - 1] &;
f9 = Module[{lst = #},  
      Function[k, Module[{t = 0}, Split[lst, ++t <= k || (t = -Length@lst) &]]] /@
       Range[0, Length[lst] - 2]] &;
```

### f10 = ReplaceList[#, {x__, y__} -> {{x}, {y}}] &; (* one word ? *)

```
☺ = ♯♯  (♯ = 1; {♯♯[[;; ♯]], ♯♯[[++♯ ;;]]} & /@ {##2 & @@♯♯}); (* no words:)*)
```

and, for formatting the outputs of the functions above

```
format = Column[Row /@ #] &;
```

Examples:

```
f1 @ Li // format
```

> [image]

```
Equal @@ Through[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, ☺} @Range[4]]
```

> True

```
f1 @ {a,b,a,c,d,b} // format
```

> [image]

```
Equal @@ Through[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, f10, ☺} @ {a,b,a,c,d,b}]
```

> True

**Notes:** I learned about the `Or` trick in `f9` from [this answer by Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105800/125). See also [this answer by Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7820/125).

Comment: Those `☺` in code always make me laugh

Comment: @yode, that's an intended side effect:)

Comment: @kglr very nice. can you kindly explain `f3` especially how the `Partition` is behaving here with all these arguments. I looked at the document but could not understand much from there

Comment: @Ali, from my reading of the docs: _Partition[list,n,d,{Subscript[k, L],Subscript[k, R]}] specifies that the first element of list should appear at position Subscript[k, L] in the first sublist, and the last element of list should appear at or after position Subscript[k, R] in the last sublist. If additional elements are needed, Partition fills them in by treating list as cyclic._  It is easier to see what this means inspecting  `Partition[Range[5], 5, 1, {-1, 1}, x]` playing with different values for the two numbers. Using `{}` instead of `x` gives a ragged partition.

Comment: ... also: the setting  _{-1,1} allow maximal overhangs at both beginning and end_

Answer (score 13):

This is literally the canonical example from the [`ReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceList.html) documentation:

> ```
> ReplaceList[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {x__, y__} -> {{x}, {y}}]
> ```
>
> {{{a}, {b, c, d, e, f}}, {{a, b}, {c, d, e, f}}, {{a, b, c}, {d, e, 
>      f}}, {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f}}, {{a, b, c, d, e}, {f}}}

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Anton & Mr.Wizard, this is `f10` in my answer; has been there since the second edit:)

Comment: @kglr Ahh, yes! (+1 on your answer then.)

Comment: @kglr I did of course already vote for your answer.  However I felt that this method and its prominence in the documentation was not given sufficient exposure, as evidenced by Anton's overlooking it earlier.  In the past I would often write the omnibus answer with every method I could think of, as you did here, but a simple and to-the-point answer is a good complement for that.

Answer (score 8):

```
Li = Range[5];

groups = Table[GatherBy[Li, # <= n &], {n, 4}]

(*  {{{1}, {2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 2, 3, 
   4}, {5}}}  *)
```

To display this as shown in your question

```
Column[StringJoin /@ Map[ToString, groups, {2}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  Or more generally,

```
Li = {a, c, b, e, d};

groups = Table[
  GatherBy[Li, Position[Li, #][[1, 1]] <= n &],
  {n, Length[Li] - 1}]

(*  {{{a}, {c, b, e, d}}, {{a, c}, {b, e, d}}, {{a, c, b}, {e, d}}, {{a, c, b, 
   e}, {d}}}  *)

Column[StringJoin /@ Map[ToString, groups, {2}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

So far only [Bob Hanlon's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151555/34008) adheres to the form required in the question.

Here is another answer producing that form:

```
Li = Range[5]
ColumnForm@Map[StringReplacePart[ToString[Li], "}{", #] &, 
 StringPosition[ToString[Li], ", "]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you don't mind the order

```
Li = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
TakeDrop[Li, #] & @@@ Catenate[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[5, {2}]] // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 5;

tra = Transpose[{
   Most@Partition[Range@n, n, 1, {-1}, {}],
   Rest@Partition[Range@n, n, 1, {+1}, {}]}];

Row /@ tra // Column
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
list = Range[5];

TakeList[list, #] & /@ 
  Sort @ Cases[IntegerPartitions[5], x : {_, _} :> Sequence[x, Reverse @ x]]


Column[%]
```

[image]